# Win32_NetworkAdapter.Index and Win32_IP4RouteTable.InterfaceIndex do not match

Tags: powershell, wmi, powershell-2.0

I am writing a script that would update DNS servers list on Windows 7 machines for the interfaces that pass traffic for default routes.

I have selected the route table entries with

```
$defaultgw_routes = Get-WMIObject Win32_IP4RouteTable | 
    Where-Object {$_.Destination -eq "0.0.0.0"}
```

and assuming the list of interfaces obtained with `Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` is in the `$interfaces` variable defined as

```
$interfaces = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration
```

I expected to join the two lists on condition `$route.InterfaceIndex -eq $interface.Index`. However I noticed that the indices do not match.

The route table has the following interface definitions:

```
C:\Users\user01>route print if 11
===========================================================================
Interface list
  ....
 13...08 00 27 8d 7e 19 ......Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT #2
 11...08 00 27 a4 16 ad ......Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT
 12...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
  ...
```

However the `$interface` list has

```
ServiceName      : E1G60
Description      : Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT
Index            : 7

ServiceName      : tunnel
Description      : Tunnel adapter Microsoft Teredo
Index            : 11

ServiceName      : E1G60
Description      : Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT #2
Index            : 13
```

That is in both lists `Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT #2` has index 13, however `Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT` is 11 in one list and 7 in the other list. What could be the reason for this "seven-eleven" discrepancy?

From the [description](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394162(v=vs.85).aspx) of the `InterfaceIndex` property I would expect that the indices should match.

> **InterfaceIndex**
>
> IP address of the next hop of this route. The value in this property is the same as the value in the InterfaceIndex property in
>   the instances of Win32_NetworkAdapter and
>   Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration that represent the network interface
>   of the next hop of the route.

Comment: `$interfaces | Format-Table InterfaceIndex, Index, ServiceName, IPAddress, Description` should explain relation of `InterfaceIndex` and `Index`.

Comment: @JosefZ thank you, that's great. I totally missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code snippet shows a possible approach to to join the two lists using [`-in` comparison operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-5.1).

```
$filterDest = "Destination = '0.0.0.0'" 
$defaultgw_routes = Get-WMIObject Win32_IP4RouteTable -Filter $filterDest
$filterIPA  = "IPEnabled = True"
$interfaces = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter $filterIPA

'### interfaces ###'
$interfaces | 
    Where-Object {$_.InterfaceIndex -in $defaultgw_routes.Interfaceindex } |
       Select-Object [a-z]* -ExcludeProperty PSComputerName, Scope, Path, Options, 
           ClassPath, Properties, SystemProperties, Qualifiers, Site, Container
'### routes ###'
$defaultgw_routes | 
    Where-Object {$_.InterfaceIndex -in $interfaces.Interfaceindex } | 
       Select-Object [a-z]* -ExcludeProperty PSComputerName, Scope, Path, Options, 
           ClassPath, Properties, SystemProperties, Qualifiers, Site, Container
```

Please note that

- pipe to `Where-Object` is replaced with appropriate `-Filter` parameter to specify a *`Where` clause* to use as a filter. Uses the syntax of the [`WMI` Query Language (WQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394606(v=vs.85).aspx), and
- pipe to `Select-Object` is added merely to avoid recurring output of well-known properties.

Comment: Nice one. Neat and clean :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check this now to understand the difference between them:

```
$interfaces = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | select InterfaceIndex, Index
$defaultgw_routes = Get-WMIObject Win32_IP4RouteTable |?{$_.Destination -eq "0.0.0.0"} | Select InterfaceIndex,Index

$interfaces 
$defaultgw_routes
```

Comment: Please note that `Win32_IP4RouteTable` instances do not have a property called `Index`, so the last line would print only one non-empty column.